# Simplification of trigonometric functions with similar arguments

Tags: trigonometry

I am looking to simplify the following:
$$\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)}{\sin(x+y)}$$
I have tried series expansion but I am unable to reconcile this as a single argument in terms of some trigonometric function. Hopefully one of you guys has a bright idea.

Comment: Now $$\sin(x+2)=\sin\left(2\cdot\dfrac{x+y}2\right)$$

Comment: I can reduce this to $\frac{1}{2}\sec\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I don't know why I didn't see that  before raising the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use that $$\sin(x+y)=2\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$$